# Angular - how to map observable inside array

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular5

I have an array of **servers** object where inside that array I have another observable array of objects, its key is **[securityGroups**].

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    forkJoin(
      this.serverService.getServer(),
      this.securityGroupService.getSecurityGroups())
      .pipe(takeWhile(() => this.alive))
      .subscribe(([servers, groups]) => {
        this.servers = servers.map((item) => ({
          ...item,
          securityGroups: this.serverService.getServerById(item.id)
            .pipe(map(server => server["security_groups"]))
        }))
        this.securityGroupArray = groups['security_groups'].map((item) => ({
          ...item,
          expanded: false,
        }))
      }
```

How can I map this **[securityGroup] key** from my server array? since it is an **Observable**. I would not like to make an asynchronous pipe in html, I would like to save it in a new array

My servers Array payload:

```
[{id: "1879f47f-1c5e-464b-bb76-e7cc13ef426e", name: "hello", flavor: {…}, securityGroups: Observable} ,
{id: "b9c7e32a-bf99-4250-83cb-13523f9c1604", name: "test01", flavor: {…}, securityGroups: Observable}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your challenge is that you receive an array of `server`s and you need to make a call for each one to retrieve more data (`securityGroup`s) and append it to the object.

To accomplish this, you'll need to "subscribe" to this secondary call somehow, so that you can receive the data. There are several "[Higher Order Mapping Operators](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/)" that can do this for you, so you don't have to deal with nested subscriptions.  In this case, we can use [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap).

In order to make a bunch of calls at one time, we can use [`forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin) to make all the calls at once and receive an array of all the results.

You're currently using `forkJoin` to make 2 different calls, but you aren't using the results from those calls for the same purpose.  I would split them up into separate observables, both for clarity of intent and so they can be used independently:

```
  securityGroups$ = this.securityGroupService.getSecurityGroups().pipe(
    map(groups => groups.map(group => ({
      ...group,
      expanded: false
    })))
  );

  servers$ = this.serverService.getServers().pipe(
    switchMap(servers => forkJoin(
      servers.map(s => this.serverService.getServerById(s.id))
    )
    .pipe(
      map(serversWithGroups => serversWithGroups.map((server, i) => ({
        ...servers[i],
        securityGroups: server.security_groups
      }))),
      // shareReplay(1) - see comment below
    ))
  );
```

You could still subscribe in your controller if you want:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.servers$.subscribe();
    this.securityGroups$.subscribe();
}
```

or your could use the [`AsyncPipe`](https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular#async-pipe) in the template:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let group of securityGroups$ | async">
    <option *ngFor="let server of servers$ | async" [value]="server.id">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let secGroup of server.securityGroups">
            {{ secGroup.name !== group.name ? server.name : '' }}
        </ng-container>
    </option>
</ng-container>
```

If you're nesting `*ngFor` then you can use the `shareReplay()` operator to prevent multiple subscriptions from executing your service methods multiple times.

Comment: If the response from `getServerById()` contains all the fields you need (*at least all the fields returned by `getServers()`*), the code for `servers$` above could be simplified a bit.

Comment: Hello, I don't understand why my selection option is replicating the servers and not just showing the servers that are not using that security group. I have a server: test01 and the security group new09 attached to it. When I open the select in my ng for the group novo09, I see the server test01, and it shouldn't, could you help me? I don't know where I'm going wrong. see an image. https://imgur.com/a/33DBM9p

Comment: The nested `*ngFor` will produce that kind of result.  I thought it looked a little strange, but wasn't sure what your intention was. It is replicating the servers because you are have  nested `*ngFor`; the outer is iterating the groups, but the inner is iterating all the servers; the result is rendering an `<option>` for every server for every group.  Are you trying to build a list of `server` or a list of `securityGroup`?

Comment: I am creating a list of servers. When clicking on the security group I need to show only the list of server that is not using the security group.

Comment: So you need to add the concept of "currently selected" group, right?  I don't see that in your code.

Comment: I have a list with ngFor of all my groups. When clicking on any security group, it opens a #attachModal modal that includes the selection option, my modal is an ng-template. This is my code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230603/discussion-between-dave-and-bizzybob).

Comment: I think it would be easier to address this concern in a separate question.  I feel this answer addresses "*How to map observable inside array*".  Please post a new question with relevant code (template and controller)  for "*How to filter list based on selected value?*" (or possibly better description :-); then I will take a look .

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve all inner observable with `forkJoin` and map it to `securityGroups` prop of `server` object

```
this.serverService.getServer()
.pipe(switchMap((servers) => {
   return from(servers).pipe(mergeMap((server) => {
      return forkJoin(server.securityGroups)
      .pipe(map((_securityGroups) => {
         server.securityGroups =_securityGroups
         return server;
      }))
   }))
}))
```